# Numeric Reference Numbers (for Development Purpose) in acmsmall Format

Tags: bibtex, acm

I am using the `acmsmall` template to write a journal. However, the references appear as Author-Year style. While I am writing the article, I would prefer to have numeric references. I will revert to the original citation format when I submit it. How can I do that? MWE below.

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtopc]{acmsmall} % Aptara syntax
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,sort,compress]{natbib}


\begin{document}
This was explained in \cite{author_book}.

\bibliographystyle{ACM-Reference-Format-Journals}
\bibliography{jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to add the year to your .bib-entries. The date will not suffice.

Comment: This is a minimum working example. The full tex and bib file have year of course.

Comment: Use `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`.

Comment: I used plainnat, but it is not working. Maybe something to do with the acmsmall package.

Comment: I had a similar issue. Commenting out `\citestyle{acmauthoryear}` did the job.